# Registry createSubKey under LocalMachine

Tags: c#, safenet

When I try to apply these codes like below, It doesnt get an success result when I check the subdirectory SOFTWARE\Safenet\PTKC\WLD. Is there anybody what is the reason of this issue.

```
RegistryKey Location = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Safenet\PTKC", true);
RegistryKey newKey = Location.CreateSubKey("WLD", true);
newKey.SetValue("data", "value");
Location.Close();
```

Comment: Are you running this code as a user with the right permissions?

Comment: running as an admin privilage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was probably created in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regedit.exe. Try building your application with only x64.